How to colour each number differently in latex subscript
I have the following latex I am using in Lucidchart application:
\omega_{11}^{\ell}

I want the first 1 to be a red colour and the second 1 to be a green colour. How do I achieve that?
I have tried the following:
\omega_{1{red}1{green}}^{\ell}

but it doesn't lead to the right result.

Dan, looks like you got an answer, but for the record, you might get more eyes on a LaTeX problem at tex.stackexchange.com.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\[
\omega_{\mathcolor{red}{1}\mathcolor{green}{1}}^{\ell}
\]
\end{document}



Thanks very helpful. Although Lucidchart does not support the use of the above construct. This worked though: \omega_{\color{red}{1}\color{green}{1}}^{\ell}
